# Pandas where function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas where function trying to find the percentage in each state

```
filter1 = df['state']=='California'
filter2 = df['state']=='Texas'
filter3 = df['state']=='Florida'

df['percentage']= df['total'].where(filter1)/df['total'].where(filter1).sum()
```

The output is

```
Year    state         total    percentage
2014    California  914198.0    0.134925
2014    Florida     766441.0    NaN
2014    Texas      1045274.0    NaN
2015    California  874642.0    0.129087
2015    Florida     878760.0    NaN
```

how do I apply the rest of 2 filters into there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `where` but `groupby.transform`:

```
df['percentage'] = df['total'].div(df.groupby('state')['total'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
   Year       state      total  percentage
0  2014  California   914198.0    0.511056
1  2014     Florida   766441.0    0.465865
2  2014       Texas  1045274.0    1.000000
3  2015  California   874642.0    0.488944
4  2015     Florida   878760.0    0.534135
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out `df.loc[(filter1) & (filter2) & (filter3)]` in pandas to apply multiple filter together !